# CString formatting currency

Tags: mfc, currency, c-strings

Good evening, could you tell me if a class or a method exists in MFC visual C++ which takes a `CString` type and formats it in currency… i.e `CString str; str = _T("12345,67")` and `str` becomes= `12.345,67` or `str = 5000` and becomes `str = 5.000,00`

I've also tried to create a method but without success

Thanks who will be able to help me… I know it would be easier to add the points as separators where it needs, but when I need to convert the `CString` in double it truncates from the first point to the end.

I don't have a solution

Comment: Did you look at the [COleCurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/colecurrency-class?view=msvc-170) methods, ParseCurrency and Format?

Comment: Yeah but Format is unuseful because it just formats a string with decimals and not by the separators... COleCurrency and ParseCurrency I don't know how to use them

Comment: Not sure if you checked the link that @lakeweb referred to. He was on about `COleCurrency::Format`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the [`GetCurrencyFormatEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getcurrencyformatex) function for this.

To quote the article:

> Formats a number string as a currency string for a locale specified by name.

---

As for [`COleCurrency`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/colecurrency-class?view=msvc-170), you are not left to work it out for yourself. There is documentation. I admit I have not used this class, but it implies that `COleCurrency::Format` will do what you want:

> Returns a `CString` that contains the formatted currency value.

Sample code is provided:

```
COleCurrency curA;           // value: 0.0000
curA.SetCurrency(4, 500);    // value: 4.0500

// value returned: 4.05
curA.Format(0, MAKELCID(MAKELANGID(LANG_CHINESE,
   SUBLANG_CHINESE_SINGAPORE), SORT_DEFAULT));
// value returned: 4,05
curA.Format(0, MAKELCID(MAKELANGID(LANG_GERMAN,
   SUBLANG_GERMAN_AUSTRIAN), SORT_DEFAULT));
```

---

[`ParseCurrency`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/colecurrency-class?view=msvc-170#parsecurrency) is also documented and again, a sample is provided:

```
// works if default locale has dot decimal point
COleCurrency cur;
cur.ParseCurrency(_T("$135.95"), 0);
ASSERT(cur == COleCurrency(135, 9500));
```